# Python Pandas dataframe to pdf table: the column title and the cell is overlapping and the cell split up

Tags: html, python-3.x, dataframe, pdfkit

I have one CSV file from where I am getting my data. After doing some process, I have made one data frame 'abstand'. The bk_color_cell function changes the cell background color based on its value. After that I am generating one html and rendering the data using data frame.style.applymap. At the end using pdfkit I am generating a pdf file.
It works, but the problem is, the column at the end of the page is splitting up and the column title is also overlapping with the data. Img 1 can give a better idea.
Is there any way, so the column does not split upand the column title does not overlap with the data?
[image]

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pdfkit
import PyPDF2
import docx
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
import datetime 
import math
from IPython.display import display, HTML, display_html
from itertools import chain,cycle

EncoderObenPos0 = []
ImageCounter = []
myInt = 1
fileName = "Test2"
fileFormat = ".csv"
# load needed data column 
eop0 = pd.read_csv(fileName+fileFormat, sep=',', usecols=[2], squeeze=True)

imgCount = pd.read_csv(fileName+fileFormat, sep=',', usecols=[10], squeeze=True)

for imgCount in imgCount: 
       ImageCounter.append(imgCount)
imageNo = ImageCounter.pop()-1

if imageNo != 1: 
        for eop0 in eop0: 
            if eop0 > 0:
                eop0 = eop0 - (imageNo*60)
                EncoderObenPos0.append(eop0*0.001)    

# Store encoder values to another array list for further processing
Abstand_ObenEncoder0 = EncoderObenPos0

#open the html file to fill it with the data
f = open('exp.html','w')


länge = ImageCounter[0]*60*0.001

Abstand_ObenEncoder0[:] = [x / myInt for x in Abstand_ObenEncoder0]

# now round those encoder float values to  max value
i = 0
split_Abstand_obEn0 = []

while i < len(Abstand_ObenEncoder0):
    x = math.modf(Abstand_ObenEncoder0[i])
    if x[0] > 0:
        y = round(x[1]+1)
    split_Abstand_obEn0.append(y)
    i += 1
i = 0  

# will devide the total legth of the material based on how many images got taken
# and we will devide the total length of the material to know how many cells will be needed 
for the chart

partition= länge/1
partition = math.modf(partition)
if partition[0] >0:
    partitionNo = round (partition[1] + 1)

# make 0 array with the legth of the cell count     
abs_EnOb0 = [0]* partitionNo

#add the devided and rounded encoder values to the array, without any repeatation
for x in split_Abstand_obEn0:
    abs_EnOb0[x-1]= x

# make table of the original encoder values in meter
abstand =  {'Einbrandkerbe HSS (Oben)': abs_EnOb0}
abstand = pd.DataFrame(abstand)
abstand.index += 1

def bk_color_cell(cell):
   return 'background-color: ' + ('red' if cell > 0 else 'green')

html = abstand.style.applymap(bk_color_cell).render()

print (html)
#abstand = abstand.to_html()    
f.write(html)
f.close()
pdfkit.from_file('exp.html', 'out.pdf')
```

Comment: please share `exp.html` and `Test2.csv` files